# How to print "" in php varible in html file

Tags: php, html, algorithm

Okay so when I do:

```
<br>
$line9 = "<button onclick='window.location.href='//home-pc/';'/>GoBack</button>";
$phpfiletxt
"$line1\n$line2\n$line3\n$line4\n$line5\n$line6\n$line7\n$line8\n$line9\n$line10\n$line11\n$line12\n$line13\n$line14\n$line15";<br>
$myfile = fopen("$folder/index.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");<br>
fwrite($myfile, $phpfiletxt);<br>
fclose($myfile);<br>
$wordlink = "<a class='list' target='_top' href='$folder'>$word</a>";<br>
$myfile = fopen("wordslist.php", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");<br>
fwrite($myfile, $wordlink);<br>
header("Location: $folder");<br>
```

where the button is i want to make it work because it doesn't do anything becuase the ' or " arent placed correctly

so i need it so this is a varible that i can print:

```
onclick='window.location.href='//home-pc/';'/>GoBack</button>";
```

into an html file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In relation to :

> How to print "" in php varible in html file

You do as follows:

```
$string = "The man said\"Hello\" and ran away!";

echo $string;
```

result: The man said"Hello" and ran away!

It's called escaping. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='/home/pc'">GoBack</button>;
```

Is what you need to replace that with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$line9 = "<button onclick=\"window.location.href='//home-pc/';\">GoBack</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use ' instead of ", because **html** has so many " need to be escape like \"...\"

```
$string = '<a class="text-success" id="success">success></a>'
```